# Asp.Net Application Properly using .RowFilter to Textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, if-statement, ado.net, switch-statement

In the application im writing im connecting to a SQL database, then using an `Adapter` to hold the returned results but now I want to filter the results with `.RowFilter` three times return the filtered result each time to Textbox. I'm not sure if this is best executed with an `if` statement or with some `Switch` statement. Heres the code for a better idea of what im trying to do.

```
using (con)
{
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(selectSQL, con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@num", IDnumber);
   //SQLConnection Established and Opened
    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(selectSQL, con);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    adapter.Fill(dt);
   //Adapter Created and Filled

    DataView dvQ = dt.DefaultView;

    dvQ.RowFilter = "AccountType = Q"; 
    QualVol.Text = "TotalVolume".ToString();
   //First Filter then Change QualVol textbox text to Column data TotalVolume

    dvQ.RowFilter = "AccountType = N";
    NonVol.Text = "TotalVolume".ToString();
    //Filter original DataView then Change NonVol textbox text to Column data TotalVolume

    dvQ.RowFilter = "AccountType = M";
    MidVol.Text = "TotalVolume".ToString();
    //Filter original DataView then Change NonVol textbox text to Column data TotalVolume
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As per dotnetperls performance of a `switch` is better than an `if` but also gives a good clue on what situation an if performs better than the switch

http://www.dotnetperls.com/if-switch-performance